# Weird stripes when using subdivision modifier

Tags: lighting, artifacts

So i'm creating a rifle and i encountered some weird artefact. I created a plane,subdivided it couple of times, added shrinkwrap  and then added solidify  modifier to make some details.
I applied evertyhing and then i saw some weird stripes. They aren't any real mesh bumps but rather a shading bug. How can this be fixed?

[image: stripes]

[image: editmode]

Comment: did u try shade autosmooth?

Comment: yes it's already turned on

Comment: Can u provide blend file?

Comment: I guess i fixed it, i used Lattice with shrinkwrap to bend it and made the cube child of the Lattice. That fixed the issue as i wasn't directly bending the object. Thanks for help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I guess i fixed it, i used Lattice with shrinkwrap to bend it and made the cube child of the Lattice. That fixed the issue as i wasn't directly bending the object.